# libsass bindings not found when using node-sass in nodejs

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, libsass, node-sass

I want to use the `node-sass` module in my `node.js v0.12` application to benefit from the performance of `libsass`.
I executed `npm i node-sass` to install the module, no errors so far.

Now the mess starts:
If I just open the `REPL` in a terminal to try out `node-sass` then everything works fine but if I include it in my project files and run `node myfile.js` then I get the following error message:

```
Error: `libsass` bindings not found. Try reinstalling `node-sass`?
```

The module's description at [npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass#install) states that there might be a problem with resolving `#!/usr/bin/env node` under Ubuntu and how to fix this but that is not the case on my machine.
I could not find anything useful so I hope that you might help me.

I'm using node v0.12.2 under Ubuntu 14.10.

P.S.: I already tried to reinstall node-sass but without success. Nothing changes.

Comment: If Philipp's answer solved your issues, please accept. It fixed my issue.

Comment: I ran into this within my Ionic project after I updated to the lated NodeJS release -- the out put instructs to run a `npm rebuild node-sass`, which got rid of the error for me/my environment.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

You’ve probably tried to reinstall node-sass while using

```
npm install node-sass
```

or

```
npm uninstall node-sass
npm install node-sass
```

But node-sass is a C version of Sass. You have to use [npm rebuild](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/rebuild):

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```

Comment: When I try the rebuild command I get the error 'Error: Can't find Python executable "python"... Not sure mine is a C version of Sass

Comment: @Sebastian Native Abstractions for Node (nan) "change dramatically from one release to the next" and often need to be recompiled for each release. `node-sass` is entirely about binding `node` to `lib-sass`, a C program.
links: [node addons](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html#addons_native_abstractions_for_node_js), [a celebrated comment](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1527#issuecomment-217070514), [libsass](http://sass-lang.com/libsass)

Answer (score 273):

If you're using node 4.x or later then you need to reinstall gulp-sass with:

```
npm uninstall --save-dev gulp-sass
npm install --save-dev gulp-sass@2
```

Comment: Thank you! I always forget how to solve this issue, and by far this was the simplest and quickest solution.

Comment: This fixed my issue! Was a result of updating node significantly.

Comment: I didn't do like this but just changed the version number in package.json file manually to `2.1.0` from `1.x.x`.

Comment: This finally did it for me, unlike pretty much every other reply to this question. +1

Comment: Thank you Thank you Thank you! This little issue killed a demo once and I was afraid to upgrade and reverted back to 0.12.7, today I tried again, had the issue occur and this fixed it!

Comment: this fixed it for me too...after weeks of trying other solutions and not having a test suite on my project. Thanks

Comment: thank you!! banging my head on this one for an hour now

Comment: This also worked exactly as written but for 'grunt-sass' instead of 'gulp-sass' if using grunt. (I have no idea how it worked... but it did)

Comment: Yeah this fixed it thanks  it was driving me nuts.. Also manually compiled libsass sassc but i dont think i need to doing this

Comment: this is fixing it for node 0.12.0.

Answer (score 20):

I fixed this issue by deleting the existing `/node_modules` folder and running `npm update`

Comment: tried this actually but in this case the /node_modules was under SVN control... deleting the directory threw the SVN tree out of sync. It's somewhat of a good option otherwise!

Comment: This happens to me from time to time as well, and deleting `node_modules` and re-running `npm install` works for me as well.

Comment: Source control is a bad place to store dependencies for this reason! It requires complete lockstep of all your environments. `package.json` is designed to describe your dependencies, and you should use something else to install your dependencies on your boxes. (having a script that calls npm install, or a docker container, or or or)

Comment: Maybe he wanted a complete lockstep of all his environments? -- Predictable and Reproducible Builds != Bad idea.

Comment: Thats is what package.json is for. You don't want to store all the node_modules non-sense in source control.

Comment: I did similar thing. but before that I manually changed the gulp-sass version to  `2.1.0.` which worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: @AFD While I agree that storing `node_modules` in source control is not ideal, `package.json` on its own does not freeze the versions. You can easily specify a specific version of a dependency within your `package.json`, but you have no control over how versions are declared within that dependency's `package.json`.

Answer (score 8):

This is the only solution that worked for me,

```
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n 0.12.7
npm install node-sass@2
sudo npm -g install node-gyp@3
npm rebuild node-sass
```

Answer (score 7):

This workaround (http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/error-running-gulp-sass/32311/20) worked form me.

Starting with this setup:

Cordova CLI: 5.3.3
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.0
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.0
Ionic Version: 1.1.0
Ionic CLI Version: 1.6.5
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.3.9
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: 5.0.1 
OS: Mac OS X Yosemite
Node Version: v4.1.1
Xcode version: Xcode 6.4 Build version 6E35b

I've found a solution to avoid to use 'sudo' command. We need before to fix npm permissions following this: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions and fixing permissions for Node here: http://mawaha.com/permission-fix-node-js/ After this we can check and reinstall software without 'sudo' for npm, n or ionic.

I followed this step:

```
npm install -g n
rm -R node_modules/ 
npm install node-sass@3.3.3 
npm -g install node-gyp@3
npm uninstall gulp-sass
npm install gulp-sass@2 
npm rebuild node-sass 
ionic setup sass
```

Why node-sass@3.3.3? Because it works with latest ionic version: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/pull/4449

Comment: Thank you so so so so so much. Finally fixed it after 2 hours <3

Answer (score 5):

Combining the two answers above worked for me, plus additions:

```
sudo npm uninstall --save gulp-sass
npm install --save gulp-sass@2
npm update
npm rebuild node-sass
```

Answer (score 3):

I have solved this to create the right directory with the specified binding.node file. You can download the bindings from github

https://github.com/sass/node-sass-binaries

Look in the error message the path where it tries to find the binding. In my case:

C:\Users\Martijn\Documents\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-46

So I create this map win32-x64-46 and copy the binding from github in.

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to downgrade to `v0.10.25` (try `sudo n 0.10.25` if you  use `n`)

Answer (score 1):

For me, this issue was caused in my build system (Travis CI) by doing something kind of dumb in my `.travis.yml` file. In effect, I was calling `npm install` *before* `nvm use 0.12`, and this was causing `node-sass` to be built for `0.10` instead of `0.12`. My solution was simply moving `nvm use` out of the `.travis.yml` file’s `before_script` section to before the `npm install` command, which was in the `before_install` section.

Answer (score 1):

This was a Node version issue for me, try using nvm to backtrack your version to something like: 0.10.32. This worked for me. I was running 4.2.2

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by [updating my gcc from 4.4.x to 4.7.x](https://superuser.com/questions/381160/how-to-install-gcc-4-7-x-4-8-x-on-centos)

Answer (score 0):

No need for sudo or re-installations.  This has always worked for me:

```
nvm use 0.12.2
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the steps I undertook to fix my issue.

1. I updated my node manually to the latest version
2. Reinstalled node-sass

npm install node-sass

3.npm audit fix to fix certain vulnerabilities.

```
`npm audit fix`
```

5.npm install node-sass

```
 `npm install node-sass`
```

worked and compiled properly thereafter.
I apologize if anything related to my answer isn't right. I'm just a beginner.
Hope it works for you