# libsass bindings not found when running gulp dist

Tags: linux, node.js, gulp, bower, node-sass

I'm trying to use a gulp project on my Linux machine. The readme for the project tells me to first run `sudo npm install -g gulp bower`, then in the project directory run `sudo npm install` and then `bower install`. Everything up to this point works just fine for me. However, after that I try to run `gulp dist` and get this error:

```
Error: `libsass` bindings not found in /[PROJECT DIRECTORY]/trunk/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-14/binding.node. Try reinstalling `node-sass`?
```

Googling that error produced this: [libsass bindings not found when using node-sass in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29461831/libsass-bindings-not-found-when-using-node-sass-in-nodejs), which I tried, but that didn't fix anything. When I looked through that directory that gulp said it couldn't find the difference was the `linux-x64-14`, mine said `linux-x64-11`, so I'm assuming I have the wrong version? Just for fun I decided to try changing the name of that folder to what it wanted, and I got a different error:

```
Error: Module did not self-register.
```

The really strange thing about all this is that when I tried getting this project working on my Windows machine I didn't have any of these issues, it just worked. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by [updating GCC from 4.4.x to 4.7.x](https://superuser.com/questions/381160/how-to-install-gcc-4-7-x-4-8-x-on-centos).
Because GCC 4.4.x cannot compile node-sass of current version.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me using below commands. Try it

`npm rebuild node-sas`s

```
rm -rf node_modules

npm i
```

Answer (score -1):

This error usually shows up for us when we update our node or io.js version.

I would recommend deleting your node_modules folder and running `npm install` again.

If that doesn't work it is probably worth deleting your npm cache. There are a number of ways to do it including just a simple `npm cache clean`

I would also recommend deleting your `~/.npm` folder as well just to be sure.

If this doesn't work let me know and we can start debugging your actual Node version and your package.json

Comment: I tried that but I am still getting the same problem.

Comment: can you give me more information? what version of Node / IO.js are you using? Maybe post your package.json (or the relevant parts) so we can try to recreate your issue?