# "Error: The `libsass` binding was not found..." in nodejs 4.2.4 lts but not 5.4.1 using docker

Tags: node.js, docker, sass, libsass

I am setting up a docker container using nodejs 4.2.4 with expressjs using sass.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:4.2.4-wheezy
COPY myapp /srv/www/
RUN rm -r /srv/www/node_modules || echo "Not removing /srv/www/node_modules,     directory did not exist"

#RUN npm update
#RUN npm install -g --silent node-sass
RUN cd /srv/www && npm install --silent
#RUN cd /srv/www && npm rebuild node-sass

EXPOSE 3000
```

The express.js project was generated using their generator

```
 express -css sass --hbs myapp
```

which generates a skeleton project with this package.json:

```
{
 "name": "myapp",
 "version": "0.0.0",
 "private": true,
 "scripts": {
   "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
   "dependencies": {
   "body-parser": "~1.13.2",
   "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
   "debug": "~2.2.0",
   "express": "~4.13.1",
   "hbs": "~3.1.0",
   "morgan": "~1.6.1",
   "node-sass-middleware": "0.8.0",
   "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0"
  }
}
```

Running this on my mac with node 4.2.4 works fine, but running it within the docker container gives the following error:

```
philipp@Philipps-MacBook-Pro:~/node/expressv1 $docker run -it -P -w="/srv/www/" test_server_7 npm start 
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@2.14.12
npm info using node@v4.2.4
npm info prestart myapp@0.0.0
npm info start myapp@0.0.0

> myapp@0.0.0 start /srv/www
> node ./bin/www

/srv/www/node_modules/node-sass-middleware/node_modules/node-sass/lib/extensions.js:158
    throw new Error([
    ^

Error: The `libsass` binding was not found in /srv/www/node_modules/node-sass-middleware/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-46/binding.node
This usually happens because your node version has changed.
Run `npm rebuild node-sass` to build the binding for your current node version.
    at Object.sass.getBinaryPath (/srv/www/node_modules/node-sass-middleware/node_modules/node-sass/lib/extensions.js:158:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/www/node_modules/node-sass-middleware/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:16:36)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/www/node_modules/node-sass-middleware/middleware.js:3:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
```

However, if I extend the docker image from 5.4.1-wheezy it works fine. There seem to be quite some problems with libsass and node ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34617529/error-the-libsass-binding-was-not-found), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31386793/libsass-bindings-not-found-when-running-gulp-dist) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29461831/libsass-bindings-not-found-when-using-node-sass-in-nodejs?rq=1)). I tried all of the suggestions in those links with some still remaining in the Dockerfile above, but none of them had any effect. In a way it also does not make sense to me that I would have to rebuild node-sass if I am coming from a clean node installation. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone running into the same problem, the issue, as pesho suggested [here](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/issues/88#issuecomment-172554082), was that npm 2.x which gets installed by nodejs 4.2.4 does not run scripts when in *root* mode, causing these two scripts to fail:

```
npm WARN cannot run in wd node-sass@3.4.2 node scripts/install.js (wd=/srv/www/myapp/node_modules/node-sass-middleware/node_modules/node-sass)
npm WARN cannot run in wd node-sass@3.4.2 node scripts/build.js (wd=/srv/www/myapp/node_modules/node-sass-middleware/node_modules/node-sass)
```

One could have run npm install with the --unsafe-perm flag, but as the flag suggests, it's unsafe. A better way would be to follow Starefossens [best practices](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/issues/36) and create another user.