# `libsass` bindings not found after node 4 upgrade

Tags: node.js, gulp-sass, node-sass

I have just upgraded nodejs from version 0.12.7 to 4.0.0 (on Windows 10).

After that, when I try to run `gulp-sass` (which then runs `node-sass`) to compile SCSS files, I get this error:

```
Error: `libsass` bindings not found in C:\x\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-46\binding.node. Try reinstalling `node-sass`?
at Object.sass.getBinaryPath (C:\x\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\lib\extensions.js:150:11)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\x\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:16:36)
at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\x\node_modules\gulp-sass\index.js:163:21)
at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
```

I have tried the [fixes suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29461831/libsass-bindings-not-found-when-using-node-sass-in-nodejs), but none of them work, so this is not a duplicate question, rather, I believe this is directly related to the node upgrade. I have reproduced this behaviour on three different Windows (7 and 10) machines.

Comment: 0.12.7 to 4.0.0... Time machine works!

Answer (score 1):

Doh, it actually worked to remove `node_modules` and reinstall using `npm install`