# Ionic - Can't start gulp

Tags: css, node.js, gulp, ionic-framework

After running:

```
ionic setup sass
```

And installing all dependencies, when I try to start `gulp`, I have this error instead:

```
/Users/user/Sites/ionic/project/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:22
    throw new Error('`libsass` bindings not found. Try reinstalling `node-sass`?');
    ^

Error: `libsass` bindings not found. Try reinstalling `node-sass`?
```

I'm trying to reinstall node-sass, but no success so far. Any idea on how to fix this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [libsass bindings not found when using node-sass in nodejs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29461831/libsass-bindings-not-found-when-using-node-sass-in-nodejs)

Answer (score 1):

This [workaround](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/error-running-gulp-sass/32311/20) has fixed all.

Starting with this setup:

*Cordova CLI: 5.3.3 Gulp version: CLI version 3.9.0 Gulp local: Local version 3.9.0 Ionic Version: 1.1.0 Ionic CLI Version: 1.6.5 Ionic App Lib Version: 0.3.9 ios-deploy version: Not installed ios-sim version: 5.0.1 OS: Mac OS X Yosemite Node Version: v4.1.1 Xcode version: Xcode 6.4 Build version 6E35b*

I've found a way to avoid to use 'sudo' command. We need before to fix npm permissions following this: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions and fixing permissions for Node here: http://mawaha.com/permission-fix-node-js/ After this we can check and reinstall software without 'sudo' for npm, n or ionic.

I followed this step:

```
npm install -g n
rm -R node_modules/ 
npm install node-sass@3.3.3 
npm -g install node-gyp@3
npm uninstall gulp-sass
npm install gulp-sass@2 
npm rebuild node-sass 
ionic setup sass
```

Why node-sass@3.3.3? Because it works with latest ionic version: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/pull/4449

Answer (score 0):

Are you on Node 4? That's a somewhat common issue with the new C bindings. Here's a solution that worked for a lot:

```
 $ npm uninstall gulp-sass node-sass
 $ npm install node-sass@1.0.3
 $ npm install gulp-sass
```

Comment: When I run this commends it returns an error:

npm WARN uninstall not installed in /usr/local/lib/node_modules: "gulp-sass"
npm WARN uninstall not installed in /usr/local/lib/node_modules: "node-sass"

Answer (score 0):

I've just fixed problems with libsass or node-sass with this command:

```
$ sudo rm -rf node_modules/ && cat package.json | sed -i.bak 's/"gulp-sass": "^X.X.X"/"gulp-sass": "^2.0.4"/g' package.json && npm install && ionic lib update
```

Where X is the version of gulp-sass in your package.json

**Explanation:**

Remove the old files in node_modules. I'm not sure is necessary to use 'sudo' (in my case, yes).

```
$ sudo rm -rf node_modules/
```

---

Search and replace inside package.json updating gulp-sass version to ^2.0.4. It also creates a backup (package.json.bak),

```
$ cat package.json | sed -i.bak 's/"gulp-sass": "^X.X.X"/"gulp-sass": "^2.0.4"/g' package.json
```

---

Reinstall dependencies

```
$ npm install
```

---

Update the ionic lib in the project

```
ionic lib update
```

If you have any further problems be sure I try can help you...

Bye