# Error: The `libsass` binding was not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, libsass, node-sass

Running express app using node-sass-middleware give me this error on ubuntu:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/home/mohamed/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.7/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/home/mohamed/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.7/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@2.11.3
3 info using node@v0.12.7
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info prestart arabicoders@3.3.1
6 info start arabicoders@3.3.1
7 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 info arabicoders@3.3.1 Failed to exec start script
9 verbose stack Error: arabicoders@3.3.1 start: `node app.js`
9 verbose stack Exit status 1
9 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/home/mohamed/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.7/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:213:16)
9 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:110:17)
9 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/mohamed/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.7/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:24:14)
9 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
9 verbose stack     at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
9 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
10 verbose pkgid arabicoders@3.3.1
11 verbose cwd /home/mohamed/projects/arabicoders
12 error Linux 3.19.0-28-generic
13 error argv "/home/mohamed/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.7/bin/node" "/home/mohamed/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.7/bin/npm" "start"
14 error node v0.12.7
15 error npm  v2.11.3
16 error code ELIFECYCLE
17 error arabicoders@3.3.1 start: `node app.js`
17 error Exit status 1
18 error Failed at the arabicoders@3.3.1 start script 'node app.js'.
18 error This is most likely a problem with the arabicoders package,
18 error not with npm itself.
18 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
18 error     node app.js
18 error You can get their info via:
18 error     npm owner ls arabicoders
18 error There is likely additional logging output above.
19 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: The topic of this post seems to be [duplicated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29461831/libsass-bindings-not-found-when-using-node-sass-in-nodejs?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you don't have installed `sass` or `node-sass`.

Try with:

```
sudo su -c "gem install sass"
```

and

```
npm install -g node-sass
```

Comment: I have seen that you are using node v0.12. Have you tried to use node v4? Delete the folder `node_modules` of your project and write the command `nvm use 4` then `npm install` and try again with `node app.js`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be caused by incompatible node versions, per example, if you updated from 0.12 to 4.x or 5.x, you would have to either reinstall libsass or rebuild it with the command `npm rebuild node-sass`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running `npm rebuild node-sass` after you run `npm install`? That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

If your are using NVM, it is recommended to install & use the LTS version (currently 4.3.3). Do it using `nvm install 4.3.3 && nvm use 4.3.3`