# Node Sass missing binding for multiple node versions

Tags: node.js, npm, node-sass

I am using nvm to switch between node versions.

My package.json:

`"scripts": {
    "dev": "rm -rf public/assets/*.hot-update.js && NODE_ENV=development webpack --env=dev --progress --profile --colors",
    "prod": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --env=prod --progress --profile --colors"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.18.0",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^0.3.2",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.2",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0",
    "file-loader": "v0.10.0",
    "imports-loader": "^0.7.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.1.1",
    "postcss-cssnext": "^2.9.0",
    "sass-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "script-loader": "^0.7.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.2",
    "vue": "^2.0.3",
    "vue-lazyload": "0.7.5",
    "vue-loader": "^10.2.1",
    "vue-resource": "^1.2.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.1.8",
    "vuex": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "2.2.0",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "^1.1.0",
    "webpack-md5-hash": "^0.0.5",
    "webpack-merge": "^2.6.1",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^2.0.2"
  }`

When I am using Node v6.2.0, and run `npm run dev`, I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader?{"minimize":true}!./~/vue-loader/lib/style-rewriter.js?id=data-v-be2abeee!./~/sass-loader!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./~/@zoomcarindia/web-zap-revenue-calculator/src/components/graph/graph.vue
    Module build failed: Error: Missing binding /Users/nihar/Documents/zoomcar/web/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-48/binding.node
    Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: OS X 64-bit with Node.js 6.x

Found bindings for the following environments:
  - OS X 64-bit with Node.js 7.x
```

and when I use Node v7.8.0, I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./checklist/~/css-loader?{"minimize":true}!./~/vue-loader/lib/style-rewriter.js?id=data-v-a5234466!./checklist/~/sass-loader!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./checklist/src/components/Upload.vue
    Module build failed: Error: Missing binding /Users/nihar/Documents/zoomcar/web/checklist/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-51/binding.node
    Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: OS X 64-bit with Node.js 7.x

    Found bindings for the following environments:
      - Unknown environment (.DS_Store)
      - OS X 64-bit with Node.js 6.x
```

Whichever node version I use, it says the corresponding binding is missing.

I have tried `npm rebuild node-sass` and `rm -rf node_modules` multiple times.

Even tried `npm install --save-dev gulp-sass@2` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32946197/3639452).

Initially I had installed node using `brew`. That was v6.2.0. I removed the `system` node completely as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11178106/3639452), and then installed the same using nvm.

But the issue still persists. Please let me know what I am missing here.

Comment: Did you try `npm rebuild node-sass --force`?

Comment: just tried, didn't work.

Comment: I can reproduce the issue, but that solved it for me.

Answer (score 3):

After hours of fighting build systems, I gave up and similar to Matt above, I just grabbed the binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases

(Matt's link did not go up to Node 9)

I created the directory where the run webapp (in my case Webstorm) said it was looking for the missing binary, downloaded the binary and in my case renamed darwin-x64-59_binding.node to binding.node and tried running again -- it then worked.

Answer (score 1):

`npm rebuild node-sass` worked for VS 2017 but not for VS Code.  I had to run `npm cache clean` before it would work in VS Code.  I didn't try `npm rebuild node-sass --force` because I solved it before I found this page, so I don't know if that would have had the same effect or not.

Answer (score 0):

So I had a similar issue with node-sass and just ended up grabbing the binaries I needed from github [here](https://github.com/sass/node-sass-binaries).

For me I needed win32-ia32-48 and so I created that folder and copied in the binding.node file from the link above (after renaming it to remove the win32-ia32-48 prefix).

Answer (score 0):

None of the install/rebuild solutions resolved the issue for me (using gulp).

Here is how I resolved it:

1) Download the missing binding file from the [repository](https://github.com/sass/node-sass-binaries).

2) Rename the file `binding.node`.

3) Create directory `/node-modules/vendor/darwin-x64-51/`

4) Add `binding.node` file to `/node-modules/vendor/darwin-x64-51/`